# Recoding a table in SAS

Tags: sas

I get the following data back from an external mail system, where Mail_id is unique for a batch of e-mails.

```
Email  Mail_id    Read_date
 a      1      12.jan
 b      1      12.jan
 c      1      14.jan
 a      2      14.jan
 b      2      14.jan
 c      2      16.jan
```

I am trying to map these data back to the communication log using Email and Read_date. To do this I am making an assumption that at least one of the recipients reads the e-mail the same day that the batch is sent. In the example above 2 of 3 customers read the email 12. jan, which is the same as the Send_date in the communication log. That is all good. However e_mail "c" with Mail_id "1" read the e-mail 14.jan. Since this customers belongs to batch with mail_id = 1 I can recode this data = 12 jan., and then I'd be able to map this back to the communication log where the send date = 12 jan. As the batches are quite big this logic will be true for 99%. The recoded file will then look like

```
Email  Mail_id    Read_date
  a     1      12.jan
  b     1      12.jan
  c     1      12.jan
  a     2      14.jan
  b     2      14.jan
  c     2      14.jan
```

Thus, given the sorted table I am thinking if first.read_date and last.read_date within mail_id is the same, then do nothing, but if they are not the same then recode the entire column Read_date = first.date. But I dont know how to code this in SAS. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about the "do nothing"; just "do everything", it's no different than "do nothing" in the cases where it's the same.

```
data want;
set have;
by mail_id;
retain sent_date;
if first.mail_id then sent_date=read_date;
read_date=sent_date;
drop sent_date;
run;
```

I actually would recommend keeping read_date as the actual read_date, and instead using sent_date as a separate field, since really those are two different things.  Just remove the last two lines (other than `run;`) and you'll get that.

Comment: you could technically also do this with a quick sql statement that merges your original table and a subquery that grabs the min date of each read date as sent date, but this is probably slower than using `first.` and `last.`

Comment: Yeah, I considered that, but given the OP mentioned first/last I figured to stick to what he/she was thinking.

Comment: @Joe - thank you. But this code gives me a value for the first observation of each mail_id, but a missing for the other observations within mail_id. I was thinking to fill the column within mail_id with that first date. I tried to add "else sent_date=first.sent.date, but that only evaluates to 0. Hmmm.

Comment: Oops, I mistyped.  Retain should be `sent_date` not `read_date`; corrected.

Comment: I should have been able to see that. Thanks.